# Open a .bat file in Unix with syntax highlighting

Tags: batch-file, editor, syntax-highlighting, vi

Please suggest me a good editor where in I can open files in an editor from Unix which supports syntax high-lighting. I have been using vi editor. I tried ESC :syntax on but that did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like vi, try emacs :-)

Comment: Could you show me how do you set up the syntax highlighting in emacs please?

Comment: You might need to install an additional editing mode to get Emacs to work nicely with DOS batch files: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DosScripts

Comment: wow! sarcasm wins the accept ;)  regardless, your answer is as good as mine, congrats.

Answer (score 3):

vim works fine, you just have to tell it what a .bat file is.

If vim doesn't automatically recognize the file, you can tell it how to highlight it with `:set filetype=bat`.

Comment: Note that `vi` is not `vim`.  (though some Linux distributions make the command vi run vim;  it is definitely not the same on UNIXes like Solaris)

Comment: @dsh - which is why I recommended vim

Comment: Correct.  I just wanted to point it out since the question mentioned 'vi'.  (PS. I upvoted your answer, and edited it to also mention `:set ft=bat`)

Comment: On my install of gVim I have to use `:set ft=dosbatch`. The 'bat' file type doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is you want.. No need to use any other editor.. You can use and configure the vi editor

[VI and VIM Syntax Highlighting](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/vi-vim-syntax-highlighting-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

This is my sample screen-shot. I'm using the .bat file code from [here](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/password.bat.txt)..

[image]

This is my ~/.vimrc file configuration

```
syntax on
set background=dark
set ruler                     " show the line number on the bar
set more                      " use more prompt
set autoread                  " watch for file changes
set number                    " line numbers
set hidden
set noautowrite               " don't automagically write on :next
set lazyredraw                " don't redraw when don't have to
set showmode
set showcmd
set nocompatible              " vim, not vi
set autoindent smartindent    " auto/smart indent
set smarttab                  " tab and backspace are smart
set tabstop=2                 " 6 spaces
set shiftwidth=2
set scrolloff=5               " keep at least 5 lines above/below
set sidescrolloff=5           " keep at least 5 lines left/right
set history=200
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set linebreak
set cmdheight=2               " command line two lines high
set undolevels=1000           " 1000 undos
set updatecount=100           " switch every 100 chars
set complete=.,w,b,u,U,t,i,d  " do lots of scanning on tab completion
set ttyfast                   " we have a fast terminal
set noerrorbells              " No error bells please
set shell=bash
set fileformats=unix
set ff=unix
filetype on                   " Enable filetype detection
filetype indent on            " Enable filetype-specific indenting
filetype plugin on            " Enable filetype-specific plugins
set wildmode=longest:full
set wildmenu                  " menu has tab completion
let maplocalleader=','        " all my macros start with ,
set laststatus=2
nore ; :
nore , ;

map ,<Tab> :set hls<CR>/\\n.*\\n/<CR>
set statusline=%2*%n\|%<%*%-.40F%2*\|\ %2*%M\ %3*%=%1*\ %1*%2.6l%2*x%1*%1.9(%c%V%)%2*[%1*%P%2*]%1*%2B

"  searching
set incsearch                 " incremental search
set ignorecase                " search ignoring case
set hlsearch                  " highlight the search
set showmatch                 " show matching bracket
set diffopt=filler,iwhite     " ignore all whitespace and sync

"  backup
" set backup
" set backupdir=~/.vim_backup
" set viminfo=%100,'100,/100,h,\"500,:100,n~/.viminfo
"set viminfo='100,f1

" spelling
if v:version >= 700
  " Enable spell check for text files
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt setlocal spell spelllang=en
endif

" mappings
" toggle list mode
nmap <LocalLeader>tl :set list!<cr>
" toggle paste mode
nmap <LocalLeader>pp :set paste!<cr>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Dark background
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

"I always work on dark terminals
" set background=dark

"Make the completion menus readable
highlight Pmenu ctermfg=0 ctermbg=3
highlight PmenuSel ctermfg=0 ctermbg=7

"The following should be done automatically for the default colour scheme
"at least, but it is not in Vim 7.0.17.
if &bg == "dark"
  highlight MatchParen ctermbg=darkblue guibg=blue
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vim if you want a terminal editor. If you want a GUI one, you can use gedit, which is easy and supports highlighting for many languages.